# How to do a timestamp query in Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i would like to know how to structure a timestamp field in Firestore in order to do specific queries like:

1. Get all the documents with the same hour in a month

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve timestamp from firebase and compare with required hour.If document matches add the document to an array.Finally after comparing with all documents your array contains only documents with same hour in a month

```
Date month = new Date(); 
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
calendar.setTimeInMillis(month.getTime()); 
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6);
final String date = String.valueOf(document.get("OrderPlacedDateTime")); 
if(date.contains((CharSequence) year)) {
  //add to array
}
```

I did this in android idea might be helpful.

Comment: OP is using NodeJS though.